# Can unverified scanf call cause an undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c11

Does below snippet invoke undefined behavior in case of an error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;                      /* Indeterminate */
    if (scanf("%d", &i) == 1)   /* Initialize */
        printf("%d\n", i);      /* Success! Print read value */
    else
        printf("%d\n", i);      /* Input failed! Is printing `i` UB or not? */
    return 0;
}
```

What if scanf fails, is an uninitialized variable accessed?

**EDIT**
Moreover what if I replace `scanf("%d", &i)` with `my_initializer(&i)`:

```
int my_initializer(int *pi)
{
  double room_temp_degc = get_room_temp_in_degc();
  if(room_temp_degc < 12.0) {
    // Cool
    *pi = 42;
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C90, this is UB.

For C99 and C11, technically, it isn't, but the output is indeterminate. It's even possible, that another `printf` directly following will print a different value; uninitialized variables may appear to change without explicit action of the programme. Note, however, that an uninitialized variable can only be read if its address has been taken<sup>*)</sup> (which is done here in the `scanf` call). From n1570 6.3.2.1 p2:

> If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the `register` storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

*In theory*, this would allow for something like

```
int n;
&n;
printf("%d\n", n);
```

But compilers may still reorder statements or allocate registers based on the assumption that the first read doesn't occur before the first write and ignore the side-effect free `&n;` statement.

For any practical purpose, never read uninitialized values. First, there is no reason why you should want to; second, even an unspecified value allows surprsing optimizations: Some thought a "garbage" value could be used to gather some entropy for random numbers which lead to really bad bugs in cryptographic software, see e.g. [Xi Wang's blog entry](http://kqueue.org/blog/2012/06/25/more-randomness-or-less/). For an even wierder example, where an uninitialized value is odd after multiplication with 2, see e.g. [this blog](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined) (yes, indeterminate times 2 is simply indeterminate, not even and only otherwise indeterminate).

See also [DR 260](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_260.htm).

<sup>*)</sup> The quoted paragraph is missing in C99, but this should be considered a defect in the standard, not a change in C11. C99 makes it technically defined (for machines without trap representations) to read any uninitialized variable (though their values are still indeterminate and may still appear to change randomly, it's just not UB).

With [DR 338](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_338.htm), this was corrected, but not before C11. It was added to allow `NaT` on a Titanium platform (which exists for registers, but not for values in memory), even for integer types without trap representations. I don't know, if the `&n` in the code above has any effect on such a platform (by a strict reading of C11, it should, but I wouldn't rely on it).

Comment: Absolutely technically correct answer, but I should point out that `gcc -std=c99` has, at least in some versions, optimized as if reading indeterminate contents was UB: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined

Comment: No, the revised definition present in C11 with the “could have been declared with the `register` storage class” was never in any revision of C99, according to the timeline of DR 338. DR 338 was submitted 2007-03-09, before TC3 was finalized, but the committee did not reach an agreement in time for TC3 and the change appeared in C11. Unless you have access to the official TC3 and you insist it contains the sentence (I have draft N1256 and I can't find it anywhere in it).

Comment: Hmmm.. So ideally in `C90`, one should write extremely defensive code.

Comment: @MohitJain, I'm not sure. Is there any real use case for using uninitialized variables? Or are you talking about accidently uninitialized variables? Some compilers can warn about it, `-Wuninitialized` with GCC, for example (you may need to use optimizations to enable the necessary flow analysis). That's not reliable, however (and raises the question if it's reliable at least for the cases, where there is made use of this UB for optimization).

Comment: @mafso: The primary usage case, which occurs mainly with structures but could also occur with discrete objects that get copied into structures, would be when there is an object (that is always initialized) that indicates whether various other objects hold meaningful values.  Being able to blindly copy the "which objects hold meaningful values" flag along with all the objects that may or may not hold meaningful values, may be faster than trying to avoid copying the objects that don't hold meaningful values.

Comment: @mafso: Effectively, the goal isn't to be able to "use" uninitialized objects in a way that their value would matter, but rather to be able to copy objects' contents if they have any, without having to worry about whether they do.  Somewhat less commonly, some algorithms may be able to determine if a value is correct more quickly than they could compute it from scratch.  An operation `give me a[i] if it has been written, or else any arbitrary number` may be useful in such context, especially if most elements of a[] will never get used, and if checking a value for correctness is quick.