# sprintf() command doesnt work

Tags: c, arrays, execv

I am trying to write an c program which get two float numbers from user and then calls another program with execv() command. But I can't do it , because of converting float to char or I don't know why.
The problem is execv() command is not working; the output must be like that

> Enter first num:  5
>  Enter second num:  7
>   5.000000 + 7.000000 = 12.000000 
>  parentPID: 9745 childPID: 9746 works now

but it is is like that now

> Enter first num:  5
>  Enter second num:  7
>  parentPID: 9753
>   childPID: 9754 works now

my first c program sum.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if(argc!=3)
  printf("error...\n");
  double a=atof(argv[1]);
  double b=atof(argv[2]);
  printf("%lf + %lf = %lf \n",a,b,a+b);
  return 0;
}
```

and the second program calculate.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() 
{
  float x,y;
  pid_t pid;

  printf("Enter first num: ");
  scanf("%f",&x);
  printf("Enter second num: ");
  scanf("%f",&y);

  if((pid=fork())== -1)
  {
    printf("can not fork..\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if(pid==0) //child
  {

    pid=getpid();
    char *temp[] = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
    temp[0]="sum";
    sprintf(*temp[1],"%f",x); //here I want to convert float number to char but it doesn't work
    sprintf(*temp[2],"%f",y);
    execv("sum",temp);
  }
  else
  {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("parentPID: %d childPID: %d works now.\n", getpid(), pid);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly "I can't do it" means? What is the actual problem? Please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char command1[50], command2[50]; // Added
char *temp[] = {NULL, command1, command2, NULL}; // Modified
temp[0]="sum";
sprintf(temp[1],"%f",x); // remove *
sprintf(temp[2],"%f",y); // remove *
```

You are not `alloc`ating to `temp[1]` and `temp[2]` and using those as destination buffer in `sprintf` and using incorrect `*` in sprint.

You can use `malloc` to allocate this memory or use other string as shown in above example to initialize the array.

---

From kind comment of [Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh):

In `sum.c`, change below lines of code to:

```
if(argc!=3)
{
  printf("error...\n");
  return -1;
}
```

or else, it [may](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104910/can-unverified-scanf-call-cause-an-undefined-behavior) lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MohitJain sir, kindly mention about the requirement of an exit or return statement in case `if(argc!=3)` for the first code. Otherwise, it may lead to UB by using `argv[1]` and so.

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you made all 4 changes I suggested and recompiled properly. I suggest using gcc -W -Wall -O2 flags for compilation.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks done. Anytimes feel free to edit my answers.

Comment: Thank you @MohitJain,  it works now, after comment of Sourav Ghosh :)