# why scanf doesn't read zero

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm really newbie. I use scanf to read from the input and assign it to a variable. When I printf the variable it prints 1 instead of zero. This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a = scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("%d", a);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

scanf returns 1 as success:

```
int a = scanf("%d", &a);
```

Change this to:

```
int a;
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Comment: This is hopefully obvious, but usually `if(scanf...` should usually be used to avoid uninitialised variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104910/can-unverified-scanf-call-cause-an-undefined-behavior

Comment: Definitely! I was just answering the OP's question about why "a" had 1 in it.

Comment: thanks, it works. I'm learning c programming and doing the code forces problems I decide to learn c because it's faster in competitive programming

Answer (score 2):

`int a = scanf("%d", &a);` defines `a` to be initialized with the return value of `scanf` and asks `scanf` to put the converted value in `a`. This is wrong. Use:

```
int a;
scanf("%d", &a);
```

`scanf` returns the number of items assigned or `EOF` if an input failure occurs before the first matching is completed. You can use that to test whether input was successfully processed.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using something like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int n = scanf("%d", &a);
    if (n != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read an integer (%d)\n", n);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

The variable `n` allows you to distinguish between EOF (usually `-1`) and "the first data after white space was not part of an integer" (`n` will contain `0`).
Note that the error message is printed on standard error; that's what it is for.  You should normally print a newline at the end of output messages.

You could decide not to use `n` and then not print it in the error message:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read an integer\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

It is still important to test the result from `scanf()` so that if the user typed `zero` instead of `0`, you could spot the problem.

Note that `a` would not be assigned if the matching fails — so without the test, you'd be printing an uninitialized variable, which is not a good idea.  You could define `int a = 0;` which would avoid that problem (with any choice of `int` initializer that you like).